# AngularJS with Flickr, JSONP

Tags: json, angularjs, rest, jsonp, flickr

To be honest I really am not sure what is wrong.  I have this error from the console:

https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$resource/badcfg?p0=object

```
var portfolioServices = angular.module('portfolioServices', ['ngResource']);

portfolioServices.factory('Pictures', ['$resource',
  function($resource){
    return $resource(
       'https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/', 
       {method: 'flickr.people.getPublicPhotos', api_key: 'KEY', format:'json', jsoncallback: 'JSON_CALLBACK', user_id: '66025075@N06'} , 
       { 'load': { 'method': 'JSONP' } }
    );
  }]);
```

Yet it does not seem to work?

And here is the return for the API call:

```
jsonFlickrApi(
  {"photos":
   {"page":1,"pages":5,"perpage":100,"total":"439","photo":[
    {"id":"14302632135","owner":"66025075@N06","secret":"363d6a9cc0","server":"3724","farm":4,"title":"","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},
    {"id":"14203182086","owner":"66025075@N06","secret":"d80fc4e141","server":"2914","farm":3,"title":"Box Elder","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},
...
```

Here is the website it is running on: http://lje.me/